# Spring Freemarker Configuration, Template Not Found

Tags: spring, templates, configuration, freemarker

I have a Spring/JSF Web application which has a dependency to a module uses Freemarker templates. Here is what i did for integration:

I imported the applicationContext-freemarker-module.xml to applicationContext.xml
I added the configuration bean to applicationContext-freemarker-module.xml like below.

```
 <bean id="freemarkerConfiguration" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
   <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath*:/"/>
 </bean>
```

I put my templates to src/main/resources directory of freemarker module. 
I am reading the templates like below:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext-freemarker-module.xml");

Configuration templateConfig = (Configuration) context.getBean("freemarkerConfiguration");

Template template = templateConfig.getTemplate("template.ftl");
```

Now i tried so many values for templateLoaderPath property but i always got the "Template not found." exception.

Freemarker module's JAR is like below

```
template.ftl
applicationContext-freemarker-module.xml
com/.../ (classes)
META-INF
```

Where should i put the template files and what should i set for templateLoaderPath value?
I could not understand why "template.ftl" can not be found. I am trying to set the right value for many hours. I tried various path configurations without success.

Thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: Have you tried `<property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath:/"/>`? If the .ftl file is in the root of the jar this should works...

Comment: yes I've tried it and still can not find .ftl file. thanks a lot for reply.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you have the following

1. In your *-action servlet xml FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean configuration has the "preferFileSystemAccess" property  set to "false"
2. `<property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath*:/"/> should be
   <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath:/"/>`

   In freemarker the template loader tries to match a string "classpath:" , not "classpath*:"
3. you have the JAR file under WEB-INF/lib folder.
4. Finally, your template file under root of the jar file.

Comment: Slightly different case for me: I had "classpath:templates" and it wasn't working on Jetty, changing it to "classpath:templates/" and it works fine!

Comment: hello Jay, If my templates are under the dependency jar How can I load the templates . I use classpath*:/mailer_templates  but It doesn`t work ):

Comment: @Felix: Check the second point mentioned above. classpath should not have a *.

Answer (score 3):

Use some bean like this:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath:META-INF/freemarker/" />
    <property name="preferFileSystemAccess" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: what is equivalent of this configuration in annotation ?